# Musician/Composer tagging standards

Tags: discussion, tags

I wonder what kind of tagging policy we may have on very famous composers.

There is currently [bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach), [schubert](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schubert) and [beethoven](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beethoven) used here. But especially in the case of Bach, there are many composers by that name.

Should we have [bach-family](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach-family), [j.-s.bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j.-s.bach) instead ?

Should we add initials to all such tags ?

Answer (score 4):

I think in the case of Bach, initials are useful.  As a general rule though, I think initials should only be added when there is ambiguity.  We're safe using [beethoven](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beethoven).

As for [bach-family](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach-family), I wouldn't worry about that unless a relevant question actually came up.  If one did, I think it would probably be enough to have the details in the question; I can't imagine anyone filtering by that tag.

**Edit:** I have retagged all the [bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach) questions to [j-s-bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-s-bach), since that's who they were about.  At a minimum, it won't hurt anything since it will still pop up when "bach" is typed in a tag field, and it should provide some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with using initials, there are annoying to type and thus people will most likely not type them in that form. The maximum amount of characters a tag can take is 25, that should allow for names.

[johann-sebastian-bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/johann-sebastian-bach) is a valid tag, <s>perhaps we could drop middle names, like [johann-bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/johann-bach)</s>.

---

**Edit:** While increasing the tag character limit could be an options, I decided to **disagree on full names**.

When questions about musicians and composers are asked, their names will most likely be listed in the question. An example is seen in [the questions covering `bach`](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=bach), where people are using J.S. Bach in the title of their questions. If we do want to tag them, it's probably best to use something along the line of [bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach) or [bach-family](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach-family). I haven't decided yet which of these would be best...

Comment: No we cannot drop middle names, there is a lot of different and significant Johann-Xxxxx-Bach.

Comment: @ogerard: As not every significant name would fit and we would be creating a lot of name tags, I've updated my post to disagree on full names but to just use family tags instead.